# Open application after Incoming/outgoing calls in ios (Xamarin)

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, ios10

i am developing an app using xamarin ios and want to detect for an incoming/outgoing call events. On both these events i want to open my app for some user interactions. i know getting call information like number, duration is not possible but can i just open my application? any suggestion?

Comment: You can't bring your app to the foreground; only the user can do that. Your app can't be notified about incoming calls unless it is the foreground app when the call arrives. Your app can't be notified about outgoing calls at all.

Comment: it means my app should be foreground in order to get incoming/outgoing calls events triggered.